# VTK 7 QtWidget with Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I am trying to compile VTK 7 to use the QVTKWidgetPluing in QtCreator 3.6.1 (Qt 5.6).

I have downloaded Qt 5.6 for 32 and 64 bits (I have the folders `"C:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015 and C:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015_64"` in my Qt installation path).

I have downloaded VTK 7 and compiled with msvc2015. I have compiled for 32 bits and 64 bits with QtGroup and SHARED LIBS enabled and put the `QVTKWidgetPlugin.dll` in the corresponding `C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\plugins\designer` folder.

If I put the 32 bits .dll file in that folder, in QtDesigner -> Tools -> Form Editor -> About Qt Designer plugins, the plugin appears in the section of "Failed plugins" with the message:

> Cannot load the library ...QVTKWidgetPlugin.dll: No process found

If I put the 64 bits .dll file in the folder, in QtDesigner -> Tools -> Form Editor -> About Qt Designer plugins, the plugin appears in the section of "Failed plugins" with the message:

> QVTKWidgetPlugin.dll is not a 32 bits application

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?